# Browser shows variable refered before assign

Tags: django

[here is the image of error that i am getting in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cV94.png)

**I am new to python and hardly tried to figure out the problem of usese of variable from another if statement in the same function**

**here is my code:**

```
 def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    selected_membership_type = request.POST.get('membership_type')

    user_membership = get_user_membership(request)

    user_subscription = get_user_subscription(request)

    selected_membership_qs = Membership.objects.filter(
                    membership_type=selected_membership_type)
    if selected_membership_qs.exists():
        selected_membership = selected_membership_qs.first()
    ''' 
    ==========
    VALIDATION
    ==========  
    ''' 
    # selected_membership = selected_membership_qs.first()

    if user_membership.membership == selected_membership:
        if user_subscription == None:
            messages.info(request,"You already have this membership.Your \
                next payment is due {}".format('get this value from stripe'))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Comment: problem in the second if statement of using 'selected_membership'

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @shivam please update your question with the error you are getting in the browser, maybe also with a little part of the traceback (at least the exception that comes) so users directly understand the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the following:

```
if selected_membership_qs.exists():
    selected_membership = selected_membership_qs.first()
```

You are only assigning `selected_membership` if the `if` is `True`.
So in your case you are getting the `Variable referenced before assignment` error because the `if` is `False`.
Therefore `selected_membership` is never assigned.

If you do something like this

```
selected_membership = None
if selected_membership_qs.exists():
    selected_membership = selected_membership_qs.first()
```

it should work.

Comment: now i am getting 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'membership_type'

Comment: @shivam then you are using the `selected_membership` variable somewhere in your code with `selected_membership.membership_type`. You have to implement a little "error-handling" for the case that `selected_membership` is `None` and not a `Membership` object.

Comment: @shivam Is your problem solved now? If so, please [consider marking the answer as acceptet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) or add more information if your problem wasn't solved yet.